# How to add a new subtitle immediately after the previous one finishes with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: kdenlive

When I do Shift + S, it adds the subtitle at the monitor/preview head. But almost always I have passed a bit outside of the end time of the previous subtitle, which generates an empty space between the end of the old subtitle, and the start of the new one.

To remove that empty space, I currently have to manually mouse drag the new subtitle back to meet the previous one, which is tiring.

Is there a keyboard shortcut like Shift + S, that will add a new subtitle, but starting immediately after the previous one, without any spacing, regardless of the monitor position?

Tested on Kdenlive 22.12.3.